# DateTime difference in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have the following query on Entity Framework Core:

```
public class Question {
  public DateTime? Approved { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionModel {
  public TimeSpan ResponseTime { get; set; }
}

List<Question> questions = await context.Questions
  .Select(x =>
    new QuestionModel {
      ResponseTime = x.Approved.Value - x.Created
    }).ToListAsync();
```

But I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.
```

How can I get a DateTime difference with Entity Framework Core?

Answer (score 4):

You can use too this extension method Subtract()

```
List<Question> questions = (await context.Questions.ToListAsync())
.Select(x => new QuestionModel {
ResponseTime = x.Approved.Value.Subtract(x.Created);
})
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Operand data type datetime2 is invalid for subtract operator.

The `datetime2` suggest it's trying to translate to SQL statement. So you should try to perform this in memory (client-sided, rather than SQL Server sided).

```cs
List<Question> questions = (await context.Questions.ToListAsync())
.Select(x =>
new QuestionModel {
  ResponseTime = x.Approved.Value - x.Created
}).ToList();
```

By calling `ToListAsync()` before the select operation, you force the query to be executed. Then you get all question in memory. When you now perform `.Select` on it, it will be executed in memory and not tried to be translated to an SQL query.